# Why must the methods of a private inner interface be public?

Tags: java

I have a private inner class implementing a private inner interface. I usually omit the private modifier inside private inner classes to make the code cleaner. Unfortunately, in this situation I get "can't reduce visibility error", even though I'm not actually reducing visibility.

```
public class Foo {
    private interface IBar{
        void foo();
    }

    private static class Bar implements IBar{
        @Override
        public void foo() { // Must be public :(
        }
    }
}
```

I presume there is no way to work around this?

Comment: Because all methods of a interface must be `public`.  It makes no sense to otherwise...

Comment: @MadProgrammer it makes sense for private inner interfaces.

Comment: For a private inner class you might as well inherit from a common inner base class. I don't see the point in using private interfaces.

Comment: No, it doesn't.  An interface is you is the "public" contract.  It makes no sense to otherwise, nor is there any reasons to do other wise.

Comment: @tbsalling in my case it's because I need to create a proxy of a private inner class and Proxy.newProxyInstance(...), which requires an interface class.

Comment: @MadProgrammer yes it does. See my previous comment.

Comment: @fhucho Do you mean you omit the access modifier on the method or the class?

Comment: @KevinBowersox on the method.

Comment: A private member interface cannot be used from code outside the containing class. All members declared in a member interface/class are accessible from the containing class, independent of the visibility level you declare. Therefore it doesn't matter what visibility you use.

Comment: @Joni like I said, the reason I want to omit "public" is to make the code cleaner :)

Comment: You are asking to make Java more complicated for no good reason, which is why they didn't do what you ask for.

Answer (score 7):

All methods of an interface are `public` and `abstract`. That is the rule.

Only making them `public` makes sense because they are to be implemented by implementing classes which may be from different packages.

and even if it is an inner `interface`, it still is `interface` So rules do not change.

Comment: +1 technical the JVM doesn't allow access to private members of other classes.  The fact you can do this at all is due to code generated by the compiler.

Comment: For private interfaces it makes complete sense for interfaces methods to be private.

Comment: @fhucho But you'd never be able to implement the interface...`private` methods can not be overridden, it makes no sense...

Comment: @MadProgrammer I can create a private static class Foo with a private method and override this method in another private static class Bar.

Comment: @fhucho , you may create a static method with same name in subclass but that doesn't mean you are overriding it. It may be termed as method hiding. Same goes with private methods

Comment: @PrasadKharkar you actually can't create a static method with the same name. But you can override a private method of a private inner class.

Comment: @fhucho, what I mean is, you can create a static method in superclass and subclass with same name but that doesn't mean subclass static method overrides the superclass static method

Comment: I would like to know the reason for downvote . Can you please explain?

Comment: @fhucho Try adding the `@Overridden` tag to method in `Bar`, it will give you an error.  Try calling `super.privteMethod()` from within `Bar#privateMethod`, it will give you an error.  You can not "override" private methods.   You can use the same name, but that's not the same as overriding...

Comment: @MadPrgrammer (at)PrasadKharkar I tried to override the private method and it works completely fine.

Comment: @fhucho, we understand that you have created a private method in superclass and have a method with same name in the subclass also. But that does not mean it is overridden.

Comment: @PrasadKharkar yes it is overriden, I tested it.

Comment: @fhucho, may I please know how did you test it?

Comment: @PrasadKharkar sure, https://gist.github.com/fhucho/c775005a2846b59a8503, it prints Foo and then Bar.

Comment: I was talking about static and private **methods** not methods in static classes. In your example, even if you have static classes, the methods are still instance methods so its fine for them. I am saying that overriding concept doesn't apply to static methods and private methods

Comment: @PrasadKharkar oh, ok. But in my above comment I specifically said that "But you can override a private method of a private inner class." My whole point is that it makes sense for private inner interfaces to have private methods.

Comment: @fhucho, I think we should discuss about it :) I was saying that java doesn't allow private methods for interfaces. We will definitely discuss later.

Comment: @PrasadKharkar ok, let's discuss later :)

Answer (score 1):

All methods on an interface must be declared `public`. Not specifying an access modifier on the `foo` method causes it to be assigned `package protected` access by default.  Since `package protected` is less accessible than `public` the code is reducing the accessibility of the `foo` method.

Comment: Ok, but a private method of a private class Foo has effectively the exact same visibility as if it had the public modifier.

Answer (score 0):

All methods of an `inteface` are `public` and `abstract`. If you don't define any modifier then by default it is `public` and `abstract`.

The general rule of override is  you can't reduce the method visibility. In side a class if you don't define any modifier then by default it will be default and default is less visible then public. So here it must be public